# Can't use fontspec with LuaLatex

Tags: fontspec

I have MiKTeX 2.9 installed on Windows 7. I want to make use of the package `fontspec`, but the command `\usepackage{fontspec}` is enough to cause the following error message:

> LaTeX Error: File `ltluatex.tex' not found.

Updating `fontspec` with the MikTeX package manager didn't help.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) you'd make it a lot easier for us to help if you'd provide a minimal example document that shows us what you are doing.

Comment: your latex is too old (ltluatex is distributed as part of the base latex distribution since October 2015 release)

Comment: In case someone stumbles upon this: A minimal working example would have been 4 lines:
Some document class line, \usepackage{titlesec}, \begin{document} \end{document}.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to outdated software